# How can you prove that the naive estimator is less efficient than the OLS estimator

Tags: regression, least-squares, estimators

The "naive estimator" is an estimate of the slope obtained by joining the first and last observations and dividing the increase in the height by the horizontal distance between them.  Given that the naive estimator is unbiased, how can we verify that it is less efficient than the OLS estimator?

Comment: What is the naive estimator ?

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! If this is a self-study or homework question, please see the guidelines about the [self-study tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: the naive estimator is an estimate of the slope merely by joining the first and last observations, and by dividing the increase in the height by the horizontal distance between them. estimator for b2 is given in the problem above - @Aerandal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are unbiased, but unbiasedness is a statistical property, a result on a sample of estimates, that is if you have several data sets, the mean of the various estimates you did obtain would be the 'true'one.

In practice, one rarely has several data sets for the same model. Therefore we are also interested in the variance of the estimates, so that a particular value of the estimate, the one we will obtain ou our dataset, will be close to the 'true' value.

Therefore, the smaller variance of the estimate the better. Here, try to show that OLS estimator has a smaller variance than this one.

Comment: how can you compare the variance of the ols and the one given above? I dont know how i can show that the OLS estimator's variance is smaller as compared to the one given above.

Comment: How can I show that is has a smaller variance? @Aerandal

Comment: I am not sure what to answer you. You have two quantities and you want to show which one is the smaller.
Like in compare $x$ and $y$, the goal is to show that $x<y$

Comment: Yes i know that i must show that the OLS estimator's variance is smaller as compared to the given variance. I just don't know how i can show that. @Aerandal

Comment: Do you have the formula of the OLS variance ?

Comment: the OLS Variance= variance of residuals / E(Xi - Xbar)Squared. @Aerandal

Comment: im sorry but do you know the answer?  @Aerandal

Comment: Are you really trying ? It seems to me you just have homework due and you want an answer without trying on your own.
What is left is not complicated.

Comment: I've been trying, i just really don't know the process. @Aerandal

Comment: Both your variances have the same numerator, try to compare the denominator, ans post here to show us what you get...

Comment: OLS VAriance: E(Xi^2) - E(2XiXbar) + E(Xbar^2) > 0.5(X1^2+Xn^2) - 4(X1Xbar + XnXbar) - X1Xn.  Don't know if i'm doing it right. @Aerandal

Answer (score 1):

Actually [per this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=9kBx5CPZCqkC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=naive+slope+estimate&source=bl&ots=TKhrbSbISy&sig=ACfU3U1zLu12ugPnLYVyz4FXAoieT5axXw&hl=en&ppis=_c&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk5Mia2uzmAhUn11kKHRy7DQIQ6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=naive%20slope%20estimate&f=false) one can prove, in cases including large measurement error,  that a naive estimator may have smaller error variance than least-squares!

Relatedly in practice, I have examined more simple (which appears to be the meaning of 'naive' in referring to estimators and tests in the literature) estimators by simulating 100 random deviates of the Logistic distribution (using a Monte Carlo CDF inversion method), and recording the computed sample mean and scale (the latter from the sample standard deviation) where the scale parameter was set to one and varying selected mean values (including, 0.5).

My selected simple estimator for scale (and mean derived therefrom) was based on the so-called quantile function for the Logistic CDF. The latter is apparently linear with slope equal to the underlying scale parameter ([see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution)) times the corresponding logit. The difference between two selected quantile functions (like the 90% minus 10%) can be used to derive a naive estimate of the scale parameter. My rough observation (based on limited trial samples of 100 deviates for varying specified means) is that its precision at least matches that of the sample scale statistic. However, its performance does appear to be largely dependent on the selected two quantiles (for differing), and perhaps further, the chosen optimal quantile pair for differing may shift based on the underlying selected mean value for the Logistic distribution itself.

Note, I recommend both the sampling mean/implied scale, or the associated quantile based scale estimate/implied mean, as good starting point estimates for say the MLE on the Logistic distribution when n is large.